# Is there a way to put footnotes under its own column in parallel texts

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

This script produces footnotes under the left column. In my bilingual book this doe not make sense. How to make the same footnote but in the right column?

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
%% Additional note from LLT: you don't need fontspec or xelatex for reledmac or reledpar to work. However, if your document _does_ involve different languages with different scripts/fonts (e.g. English and Greek or Arabic etc), then it's a good idea to use those packages -- see https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfdxqhcyyjxz for an example
%
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, french, russian]{babel}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
%\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}        

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{1ex}

\setgoalfraction{0.8}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}   

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
This is the Text on the left side.\footnote{I want this footnote to be under the left column}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Русский текст с какими-то отсылками.\footnote{Отсылка на руском}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would using the `paracol` packge for producing two colum parallel text be an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've alreasy implemented everything in reledpar/reledmac and if possible I would prefer not to change much

Comment: You could try adding `\let\footnote\footnoteA
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\hsizetwocolX[A]{0.5\hsize}`. However, this does not add  a horizontal line above the footnotes in the right column.