# Easy switching between reledpar/reledmac and parcol bilingual texts

Tags: reledmac, reledpar, paracol, parallel-texts

I've encountered some problems with footnotes while using reledpar/reledmac packages for parallel text typesetting. I am writing a bilingual book and have prepared texts for different book chapters in different files. Now the body of my book looks somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
%% Additional note from LLT: you don't need fontspec or xelatex for reledmac or reledpar to work. However, if your document _does_ involve different languages with different scripts/fonts (e.g. English and Greek or Arabic etc), then it's a good idea to use those packages -- see https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfdxqhcyyjxz for an example
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian, french]{babel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}        

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
%\setlength{\parindent}{1ex}

\setgoalfraction{0.8}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}   
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \selectlanguage{russian}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart 
            Краткое послесловие и комментарий и. о. заведующего вычислительной лабораторией НИИЧАВО младшего научного сотрудника А. И. Привалова
            \pend
            \pstart 
            Предлагаемые очерки из жизни Научно-исследовательского института Чародейства и Волшебства не являются, на мой взгляд, реалистическими в строгом смысле этого слова. Однако они обладают достоинствами, которые выгодно отличают их от аналогичных по теме опусов Г. Проницательного и Б. Питомника и позволяют рекомендовать их широкому кругу читателей.
            \pend
            \pstart 
            Прежде всего следует отметить, что авторы сумели разобраться в ситуации и отделить прогрессивное в работе института от консервативного. Очерки не вызывают того раздражения, которое испытываешь, читая восхищенные статьи о конъюнктурных фокусах Выбегаллы или восторженные переложения безответственных прогнозов сотрудников из отдела Абсолютного Знания. Далее, приятно отметить верное отношение авторов к магу, как к человеку. Маг для них – не объект опасливого восхищения и преклонения, но и не раздражающий кинодурак, личность не от мира сего, которая постоянно теряет очки, не способна дать по морде хулигану и читает влюбленной девушке избранные места из «Курса дифференциального и интегрального исчисления». Все это означает, что авторы взяли верный тон. К достоинствам очерков можно отнести и то, что авторы дали институтские пейзажи с точки зрения новичка, а также не просмотрели весьма глубокого соотношения между законами административными и законами магическими. Что же касается недостатков очерков, то подавляющее большинство из них определяется изначальной гуманитарной направленностью авторов. Будучи профессиональными литераторами, авторы сплошь и рядом предпочитают так называемую художественную правду так называемой правде факта. И, будучи профессиональными литераторами, авторы, как и большинство литераторов, назойливо эмоциональны и прискорбно невежественны в вопросах современной магии. Никак не возражая против опубликования данных очерков, я тем не менее считаю необходимым указать на некоторые конкретные погрешности и ошибки.
            \pend
            \pstart 
            1. Название очерков, как мне кажется, не вполне соответствует содержанию. Используя эту действительно распространенную у нас поговорку, авторы, видимо, хотели сказать, что маги работают непрерывно, даже когда отдыхают. Это в самом деле почти так и есть. Но в очерках этого не видно. Авторы излишне увлеклись нашей экзотикой и не сумели избежать соблазна дать побольше завлекательных приключений и эффектных эпизодов. Приключения духа, которые составляют суть жизни любого мага, почти не нашли отражения в очерках. Я, конечно, не считаю последней главы третьей части, где авторы хотя и попытались показать работу мысли, но сделали это на неблагодарном материале довольно элементарной дилетантской логической задачки (при изложении которой ухитрились допустить вдобавок достаточно примитивный логический ляп, причем не постеснялись приписать этот ляп своим героям. Что характерно). Кстати, я излагал авторам свою точку зрения по этому поводу, но они только пожали плечами и несколько обиженно объявили, что я отношусь к очеркам слишком серьезно.
            \pend
            \pstart 
            2. Упомянутое уже невежество в вопросах магии как науки играет с авторами злые шутки на протяжении всей книги. Так, например, формулируя диссертационную тему М. Ф. Редькина, они допустили четырнадцать (!) фактических ошибок. Солидный термин «гиперполе», который им, очевидно, очень понравился, они вставляют в текст сплошь и рядом неуместно. Им, по-видимому, невдомек, что диван-транслятор является излучателем не М-поля, а мю-поля; что термин «живая вода» вышел из употребления еще в позапрошлом веке; что таинственного прибора, под названием аквавитометр, и электронной машины, под названием «Алдан», в природе не существует; что заведующий вычислительной лабораторией крайне редко занимается проверкой программ – для этого существуют математики-программисты, которых в нашей лаборатории двое и которых авторы упорно называют девочками. Описание упражнений по материализации в первой главе второй части сделано безобразно: на совести авторов остаются дикие термины «вектор-магистатум» и «заклинание Ауэрса»; уравнение Стокса не имеет к материализации никакого отношения, а Сатурн в описываемый момент никак не мог находиться в созвездии Весов. (Этот последний ляпсус тем более непростителен, что, насколько я понял, один из авторов является астрономом-профессионалом.) Список такого рода погрешностей и нелепостей можно было бы без труда продолжить, однако я не делаю этого, потому что авторы наотрез отказались что-либо исправлять. Выбросить непонятную им терминологию они тоже отказались: один заявил, что терминология необходима для антуража, а другой – что она создает колорит. Впрочем, я был вынужден согласиться с их соображением о том, что подавляющее большинство читателей вряд ли окажется способным отличить правильную терминологию от ошибочной и что какая бы терминология ни наличествовала, все равно ни один разумный читатель ей не поверит.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \selectlanguage{english}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart 
            A short epilogue and commentary by the head of the SRITS computing laboratory, junior scientist A.I. Privalov.
            \pend
            \pstart 
            The subject sketches about life in the Scientific Research Institute of Thaumaturgy and Spellcraft are not, in my view, realistic in the strict sense of the word. Nevertheless they possess certain virtues that favorably distinguish them from the analogous works of G. Perspicaciov and B. Pupilov and consequently permit their recommendation to a wide circle of readers.
            \pend
            \pstart 
            First of all it should be noted that the authors were able to perceive the situation and to distinguish that which is progressive in the work of the Institute from the conservative. The sketches do not evoke the kind of irritation that one experiences when reading adulatory articles about the hack tricks of Vibegallo or the enraptured transliterations of the irresponsible prognostications from the Department of Absolute Knowledge. Further, it is a pleasure to note the correct attitude of the authors to the magus as a human being. For them, the magus is not an object of fearful admiration and adulation, but neither is he the irritating film fool, a person out of this world who is constantly losing his glasses, is incapable of punching a hooligan in the face, and reads excerpts from. Difterential and integral Equations to the girl in love. All this means that the authors had assumed the proper attitude toward their subject. The authors should also be given credit for presenting the Institute environment from the viewpoint of a novice and for not missing the profound correlation between the laws of magic and the laws of administration. As to the shortcomings of the sketches, the preponderant majority of them are the result of the fundamental humanitarian orientation of the authors. Being professional writers, they time and again show a predilection for the so-called artistic verity to the so-called verity of facts. Also, being professional writers, and just as the majority of writers, they are insistently emotional and pitifully ignorant in matters of modern magic. While in no way protesting the publication of these sketches, I feel nevertheless impelled to point out certain concrete errors and inaccuracies.
            \pend
            \pstart 
            I. The title of the sketches, it seems to me, does not correspond with their content. Using the title Monday Begins on Saturday, which is indeed a widespread saying among us, the authors apparently wished to state that the magi work without respite even when they are resting. In reality such is almost the case. But it is not evident in the sketches. The authors became excessively entranced by the exotic aspects of our activities and succumbed to the temptation to proffer the more adventurous and exciting episodes. The adventures of the spirit, which constitute the essence of life in any magus, were given almost no expression in the sketches. Of course, I don’t include here the last chapter of Part Three, where the authors did attempt to depict the labor of the mind, but based themselves on the ungrateful medium of a rather dilettantish and elementary problem in logic. (Incidentally, I had expounded my viewpoint on this question to the authors, but they shrugged their shoulders and said, in something of a pique, that I took the sketches too seriously.)
            \pend
            \pstart 
            2. The aforementioned ignorance of the problems of magic as a science plays nasty jokes on the authors throughout the entire length of the book. As, for example, in formulating the M.F. Redkin dissertation theme, they admitted fourteen (!) errors. The weighty term “hyperfield,” which they obviously liked very much, is inserted improperly into the text over and over again. Apparently it’s beyond their ken that the sofa-translator radiates not an M-field, but a Mu-field; that the term “water-of-life” had gone out of usage two centuries ago; that the mysterious apparatus under the name of “aquavitometer” and a computer by the name of “Aldan” do not exist in nature; that the head of a computation laboratory very seldom checks programs — for which purpose there are programmer-mathematicians (of which we have two, whom the authors stubbornly persist in calling girls). The description of materialization exercises in the first chapter of Part Two is done in a repugnant manner: examples of wild terminology that must remain on the conscience of the authors include, “vector magistatum” and “Auers’ incantation.” The Stokes equation has no bearing whatsoever on materialization and Saturn could in no way be in the constellation of Libra at that time. (This last lapse, particularly, is all the more unforgivable since I was given to understand that one of the authors is a professional astronomer.) The list of these kinds of inaccuracies and incongruities could be extended with no great exertion, but I refrain from doing so, since the authors categorically refused to change a single item. They also refused to expunge the terminology that they did not understand: one said that it was necessary for the ambience, and the other — that it adds color. I was, by the way, forced to agree that the preponderant majority of the readers could not distinguish the correct from the erroneous terminology, and also that no matter what terminology was employed, no reasonable reader would believe it anyway.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

which produces well-aligned output 
[image]

However, due to problems with footnotes ([Is there a way to put footnotes under its own column in parallel texts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479532/is-there-a-way-to-put-footnotes-under-its-own-column-in-parallel-texts)) I have been recomoded to switch to the paracol package. 
Simpliest change I can do to make paragraphs aligned is to keep my chapters again in different files (I can't use "switching columns as it's just too much of manual work and rearrangements of the texts) but replace `\pstart\pend` blocks on something different. I tried using `\end{leftcolumn*}\begin{leftcolumn*}`

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
%% Additional note from LLT: you don't need fontspec or xelatex for reledmac or reledpar to work. However, if your document _does_ involve different languages with different scripts/fonts (e.g. English and Greek or Arabic etc), then it's a good idea to use those packages -- see https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfdxqhcyyjxz for an example
%
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, french, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
%\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}        

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{1ex}

\begin{document}   
\begin{sloppypar}


\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{leftcolumn*}
    Краткое послесловие и комментарий и. о. заведующего вычислительной лабораторией НИИЧАВО младшего научного сотрудника А. И. Привалова
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \begin{leftcolumn*}
    Предлагаемые очерки из жизни Научно-исследовательского института Чародейства и Волшебства не являются, на мой взгляд, реалистическими в строгом смысле этого слова. Однако они обладают достоинствами, которые выгодно отличают их от аналогичных по теме опусов Г. Проницательного и Б. Питомника и позволяют рекомендовать их широкому кругу читателей.
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \begin{leftcolumn*}
    Прежде всего следует отметить, что авторы сумели разобраться в ситуации и отделить прогрессивное в работе института от консервативного. Очерки не вызывают того раздражения, которое испытываешь, читая восхищенные статьи о конъюнктурных фокусах Выбегаллы или восторженные переложения безответственных прогнозов сотрудников из отдела Абсолютного Знания. Далее, приятно отметить верное отношение авторов к магу, как к человеку. Маг для них – не объект опасливого восхищения и преклонения, но и не раздражающий кинодурак, личность не от мира сего, которая постоянно теряет очки, не способна дать по морде хулигану и читает влюбленной девушке избранные места из «Курса дифференциального и интегрального исчисления». Все это означает, что авторы взяли верный тон. К достоинствам очерков можно отнести и то, что авторы дали институтские пейзажи с точки зрения новичка, а также не просмотрели весьма глубокого соотношения между законами административными и законами магическими. Что же касается недостатков очерков, то подавляющее большинство из них определяется изначальной гуманитарной направленностью авторов. Будучи профессиональными литераторами, авторы сплошь и рядом предпочитают так называемую художественную правду так называемой правде факта. И, будучи профессиональными литераторами, авторы, как и большинство литераторов, назойливо эмоциональны и прискорбно невежественны в вопросах современной магии. Никак не возражая против опубликования данных очерков, я тем не менее считаю необходимым указать на некоторые конкретные погрешности и ошибки.
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \begin{leftcolumn*}
    1. Название очерков, как мне кажется, не вполне соответствует содержанию. Используя эту действительно распространенную у нас поговорку, авторы, видимо, хотели сказать, что маги работают непрерывно, даже когда отдыхают. Это в самом деле почти так и есть. Но в очерках этого не видно. Авторы излишне увлеклись нашей экзотикой и не сумели избежать соблазна дать побольше завлекательных приключений и эффектных эпизодов. Приключения духа, которые составляют суть жизни любого мага, почти не нашли отражения в очерках. Я, конечно, не считаю последней главы третьей части, где авторы хотя и попытались показать работу мысли, но сделали это на неблагодарном материале довольно элементарной дилетантской логической задачки (при изложении которой ухитрились допустить вдобавок достаточно примитивный логический ляп, причем не постеснялись приписать этот ляп своим героям. Что характерно). Кстати, я излагал авторам свою точку зрения по этому поводу, но они только пожали плечами и несколько обиженно объявили, что я отношусь к очеркам слишком серьезно.
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \begin{leftcolumn*}
    2. Упомянутое уже невежество в вопросах магии как науки играет с авторами злые шутки на протяжении всей книги. Так, например, формулируя диссертационную тему М. Ф. Редькина, они допустили четырнадцать (!) фактических ошибок. Солидный термин «гиперполе», который им, очевидно, очень понравился, они вставляют в текст сплошь и рядом неуместно. Им, по-видимому, невдомек, что диван-транслятор является излучателем не М-поля, а мю-поля; что термин «живая вода» вышел из употребления еще в позапрошлом веке; что таинственного прибора, под названием аквавитометр, и электронной машины, под названием «Алдан», в природе не существует; что заведующий вычислительной лабораторией крайне редко занимается проверкой программ – для этого существуют математики-программисты, которых в нашей лаборатории двое и которых авторы упорно называют девочками. Описание упражнений по материализации в первой главе второй части сделано безобразно: на совести авторов остаются дикие термины «вектор-магистатум» и «заклинание Ауэрса»; уравнение Стокса не имеет к материализации никакого отношения, а Сатурн в описываемый момент никак не мог находиться в созвездии Весов. (Этот последний ляпсус тем более непростителен, что, насколько я понял, один из авторов является астрономом-профессионалом.) Список такого рода погрешностей и нелепостей можно было бы без труда продолжить, однако я не делаю этого, потому что авторы наотрез отказались что-либо исправлять. Выбросить непонятную им терминологию они тоже отказались: один заявил, что терминология необходима для антуража, а другой – что она создает колорит. Впрочем, я был вынужден согласиться с их соображением о том, что подавляющее большинство читателей вряд ли окажется способным отличить правильную терминологию от ошибочной и что какая бы терминология ни наличествовала, все равно ни один разумный читатель ей не поверит.
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \begin{rightcolumn*}
    A short epilogue and commentary by the head of the SRITS computing laboratory, junior scientist A.I. Privalov.
    \end{rightcolumn*}
    \begin{rightcolumn*}
    The subject sketches about life in the Scientific Research Institute of Thaumaturgy and Spellcraft are not, in my view, realistic in the strict sense of the word. Nevertheless they possess certain virtues that favorably distinguish them from the analogous works of G. Perspicaciov and B. Pupilov and consequently permit their recommendation to a wide circle of readers.
    \end{rightcolumn*}
    \begin{rightcolumn*}
    First of all it should be noted that the authors were able to perceive the situation and to distinguish that which is progressive in the work of the Institute from the conservative. The sketches do not evoke the kind of irritation that one experiences when reading adulatory articles about the hack tricks of Vibegallo or the enraptured transliterations of the irresponsible prognostications from the Department of Absolute Knowledge. Further, it is a pleasure to note the correct attitude of the authors to the magus as a human being. For them, the magus is not an object of fearful admiration and adulation, but neither is he the irritating film fool, a person out of this world who is constantly losing his glasses, is incapable of punching a hooligan in the face, and reads excerpts from. Difterential and integral Equations to the girl in love. All this means that the authors had assumed the proper attitude toward their subject. The authors should also be given credit for presenting the Institute environment from the viewpoint of a novice and for not missing the profound correlation between the laws of magic and the laws of administration. As to the shortcomings of the sketches, the preponderant majority of them are the result of the fundamental humanitarian orientation of the authors. Being professional writers, they time and again show a predilection for the so-called artistic verity to the so-called verity of facts. Also, being professional writers, and just as the majority of writers, they are insistently emotional and pitifully ignorant in matters of modern magic. While in no way protesting the publication of these sketches, I feel nevertheless impelled to point out certain concrete errors and inaccuracies.
    \end{rightcolumn*}
    \begin{rightcolumn*}
    I. The title of the sketches, it seems to me, does not correspond with their content. Using the title Monday Begins on Saturday, which is indeed a widespread saying among us, the authors apparently wished to state that the magi work without respite even when they are resting. In reality such is almost the case. But it is not evident in the sketches. The authors became excessively entranced by the exotic aspects of our activities and succumbed to the temptation to proffer the more adventurous and exciting episodes. The adventures of the spirit, which constitute the essence of life in any magus, were given almost no expression in the sketches. Of course, I don’t include here the last chapter of Part Three, where the authors did attempt to depict the labor of the mind, but based themselves on the ungrateful medium of a rather dilettantish and elementary problem in logic. (Incidentally, I had expounded my viewpoint on this question to the authors, but they shrugged their shoulders and said, in something of a pique, that I took the sketches too seriously.)
    \end{rightcolumn*}
    \begin{rightcolumn*}
    2. The aforementioned ignorance of the problems of magic as a science plays nasty jokes on the authors throughout the entire length of the book. As, for example, in formulating the M.F. Redkin dissertation theme, they admitted fourteen (!) errors. The weighty term “hyperfield,” which they obviously liked very much, is inserted improperly into the text over and over again. Apparently it’s beyond their ken that the sofa-translator radiates not an M-field, but a Mu-field; that the term “water-of-life” had gone out of usage two centuries ago; that the mysterious apparatus under the name of “aquavitometer” and a computer by the name of “Aldan” do not exist in nature; that the head of a computation laboratory very seldom checks programs — for which purpose there are programmer-mathematicians (of which we have two, whom the authors stubbornly persist in calling girls). The description of materialization exercises in the first chapter of Part Two is done in a repugnant manner: examples of wild terminology that must remain on the conscience of the authors include, “vector magistatum” and “Auers’ incantation.” The Stokes equation has no bearing whatsoever on materialization and Saturn could in no way be in the constellation of Libra at that time. (This last lapse, particularly, is all the more unforgivable since I was given to understand that one of the authors is a professional astronomer.) The list of these kinds of inaccuracies and incongruities could be extended with no great exertion, but I refrain from doing so, since the authors categorically refused to change a single item. They also refused to expunge the terminology that they did not understand: one said that it was necessary for the ambience, and the other — that it adds color. I was, by the way, forced to agree that the preponderant majority of the readers could not distinguish the correct from the erroneous terminology, and also that no matter what terminology was employed, no reasonable reader would believe it anyway.
    \end{rightcolumn*}
\end{paracol}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

And this is not what I need (the second column starts after the end of the first column)

Comment: Since I do not see an easy solution using paracol commands while keeping the text as it is, I would suggest to automatically merge the text and its translation paragraph by paragraph in a single thread with a suitable Python script.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `\synch` to store text in macros and `\shuffle` to put them into different columns in order.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
%% Additional note from LLT: you don't need fontspec or xelatex for reledmac or reledpar to work. However, if your document _does_ involve different languages with different scripts/fonts (e.g. English and Greek or Arabic etc), then it's a good idea to use those packages -- see https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfdxqhcyyjxz for an example
%
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, french, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
%\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}        

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{1ex}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{synch}
\newcounter{synched}\globalcounter{synched}
\newcounter{shuffle}\globalcounter{shuffle}
\newcounter{shuffled}\globalcounter{shuffled}

\newcommand{\synch}[1]% #1 = text to be synchronized
 {\stepcounter{synch}% column dependent
  \long\expandafter\gdef\csname synch@\the\pcol@currcol @\thesynch\endcsname{#1}}

\newcommand{\shuffle}{\setcounter{synched}{0}%
  \loop\stepcounter{synched}% loop over synched macros
    \setcounter{shuffle}{0}%
    \setcounter{shuffled}{0}%
    \switchcolumn[0]*
    {\loop\ifnum\value{shuffle}<\pcol@ncol% loop over columns
      \begin{nthcolumn}{\theshuffle}%
        \ifnum\value{synched}>\value{synch}%
          \stepcounter{shuffled}% count number done
          \setcounter{synch}{0}%
        \else
          \csname synch@\theshuffle @\thesynched\endcsname
          \global\expandafter\let\csname synch@\theshuffle @\thesynched\endcsname=\relax
        \fi
      \end{nthcolumn}%
      \stepcounter{shuffle}%
    \repeat}%
  \ifnum\value{shuffled}<\pcol@ncol\repeat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}   
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{leftcolumn}
    \synch{Краткое послесловие и комментарий и. о. заведующего вычислительной лабораторией НИИЧАВО младшего научного сотрудника А. И. Привалова}
    \synch{Предлагаемые очерки из жизни Научно-исследовательского института Чародейства и Волшебства не являются, на мой взгляд, реалистическими в строгом смысле этого слова. Однако они обладают достоинствами, которые выгодно отличают их от аналогичных по теме опусов Г. Проницательного и Б. Питомника и позволяют рекомендовать их широкому кругу читателей.}
    \synch{Прежде всего следует отметить, что авторы сумели разобраться в ситуации и отделить прогрессивное в работе института от консервативного. Очерки не вызывают того раздражения, которое испытываешь, читая восхищенные статьи о конъюнктурных фокусах Выбегаллы или восторженные переложения безответственных прогнозов сотрудников из отдела Абсолютного Знания. Далее, приятно отметить верное отношение авторов к магу, как к человеку. Маг для них – не объект опасливого восхищения и преклонения, но и не раздражающий кинодурак, личность не от мира сего, которая постоянно теряет очки, не способна дать по морде хулигану и читает влюбленной девушке избранные места из «Курса дифференциального и интегрального исчисления». Все это означает, что авторы взяли верный тон. К достоинствам очерков можно отнести и то, что авторы дали институтские пейзажи с точки зрения новичка, а также не просмотрели весьма глубокого соотношения между законами административными и законами магическими. Что же касается недостатков очерков, то подавляющее большинство из них определяется изначальной гуманитарной направленностью авторов. Будучи профессиональными литераторами, авторы сплошь и рядом предпочитают так называемую художественную правду так называемой правде факта. И, будучи профессиональными литераторами, авторы, как и большинство литераторов, назойливо эмоциональны и прискорбно невежественны в вопросах современной магии. Никак не возражая против опубликования данных очерков, я тем не менее считаю необходимым указать на некоторые конкретные погрешности и ошибки.}
    \synch{1. Название очерков, как мне кажется, не вполне соответствует содержанию. Используя эту действительно распространенную у нас поговорку, авторы, видимо, хотели сказать, что маги работают непрерывно, даже когда отдыхают. Это в самом деле почти так и есть. Но в очерках этого не видно. Авторы излишне увлеклись нашей экзотикой и не сумели избежать соблазна дать побольше завлекательных приключений и эффектных эпизодов. Приключения духа, которые составляют суть жизни любого мага, почти не нашли отражения в очерках. Я, конечно, не считаю последней главы третьей части, где авторы хотя и попытались показать работу мысли, но сделали это на неблагодарном материале довольно элементарной дилетантской логической задачки (при изложении которой ухитрились допустить вдобавок достаточно примитивный логический ляп, причем не постеснялись приписать этот ляп своим героям. Что характерно). Кстати, я излагал авторам свою точку зрения по этому поводу, но они только пожали плечами и несколько обиженно объявили, что я отношусь к очеркам слишком серьезно.}
    \synch{2. Упомянутое уже невежество в вопросах магии как науки играет с авторами злые шутки на протяжении всей книги. Так, например, формулируя диссертационную тему М. Ф. Редькина, они допустили четырнадцать (!) фактических ошибок. Солидный термин «гиперполе», который им, очевидно, очень понравился, они вставляют в текст сплошь и рядом неуместно. Им, по-видимому, невдомек, что диван-транслятор является излучателем не М-поля, а мю-поля; что термин «живая вода» вышел из употребления еще в позапрошлом веке; что таинственного прибора, под названием аквавитометр, и электронной машины, под названием «Алдан», в природе не существует; что заведующий вычислительной лабораторией крайне редко занимается проверкой программ – для этого существуют математики-программисты, которых в нашей лаборатории двое и которых авторы упорно называют девочками. Описание упражнений по материализации в первой главе второй части сделано безобразно: на совести авторов остаются дикие термины «вектор-магистатум» и «заклинание Ауэрса»; уравнение Стокса не имеет к материализации никакого отношения, а Сатурн в описываемый момент никак не мог находиться в созвездии Весов. (Этот последний ляпсус тем более непростителен, что, насколько я понял, один из авторов является астрономом-профессионалом.) Список такого рода погрешностей и нелепостей можно было бы без труда продолжить, однако я не делаю этого, потому что авторы наотрез отказались что-либо исправлять. Выбросить непонятную им терминологию они тоже отказались: один заявил, что терминология необходима для антуража, а другой – что она создает колорит. Впрочем, я был вынужден согласиться с их соображением о том, что подавляющее большинство читателей вряд ли окажется способным отличить правильную терминологию от ошибочной и что какая бы терминология ни наличествовала, все равно ни один разумный читатель ей не поверит.}
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \synch{A short epilogue and commentary by the head of the SRITS computing laboratory, junior scientist A.I. Privalov.}
    \synch{The subject sketches about life in the Scientific Research Institute of Thaumaturgy and Spellcraft are not, in my view, realistic in the strict sense of the word. Nevertheless they possess certain virtues that favorably distinguish them from the analogous works of G. Perspicaciov and B. Pupilov and consequently permit their recommendation to a wide circle of readers.}
    \synch{First of all it should be noted that the authors were able to perceive the situation and to distinguish that which is progressive in the work of the Institute from the conservative. The sketches do not evoke the kind of irritation that one experiences when reading adulatory articles about the hack tricks of Vibegallo or the enraptured transliterations of the irresponsible prognostications from the Department of Absolute Knowledge. Further, it is a pleasure to note the correct attitude of the authors to the magus as a human being. For them, the magus is not an object of fearful admiration and adulation, but neither is he the irritating film fool, a person out of this world who is constantly losing his glasses, is incapable of punching a hooligan in the face, and reads excerpts from. Difterential and integral Equations to the girl in love. All this means that the authors had assumed the proper attitude toward their subject. The authors should also be given credit for presenting the Institute environment from the viewpoint of a novice and for not missing the profound correlation between the laws of magic and the laws of administration. As to the shortcomings of the sketches, the preponderant majority of them are the result of the fundamental humanitarian orientation of the authors. Being professional writers, they time and again show a predilection for the so-called artistic verity to the so-called verity of facts. Also, being professional writers, and just as the majority of writers, they are insistently emotional and pitifully ignorant in matters of modern magic. While in no way protesting the publication of these sketches, I feel nevertheless impelled to point out certain concrete errors and inaccuracies.}
    \synch{I. The title of the sketches, it seems to me, does not correspond with their content. Using the title Monday Begins on Saturday, which is indeed a widespread saying among us, the authors apparently wished to state that the magi work without respite even when they are resting. In reality such is almost the case. But it is not evident in the sketches. The authors became excessively entranced by the exotic aspects of our activities and succumbed to the temptation to proffer the more adventurous and exciting episodes. The adventures of the spirit, which constitute the essence of life in any magus, were given almost no expression in the sketches. Of course, I don’t include here the last chapter of Part Three, where the authors did attempt to depict the labor of the mind, but based themselves on the ungrateful medium of a rather dilettantish and elementary problem in logic. (Incidentally, I had expounded my viewpoint on this question to the authors, but they shrugged their shoulders and said, in something of a pique, that I took the sketches too seriously.)}
    \synch{2. The aforementioned ignorance of the problems of magic as a science plays nasty jokes on the authors throughout the entire length of the book. As, for example, in formulating the M.F. Redkin dissertation theme, they admitted fourteen (!) errors. The weighty term “hyperfield,” which they obviously liked very much, is inserted improperly into the text over and over again. Apparently it’s beyond their ken that the sofa-translator radiates not an M-field, but a Mu-field; that the term “water-of-life” had gone out of usage two centuries ago; that the mysterious apparatus under the name of “aquavitometer” and a computer by the name of “Aldan” do not exist in nature; that the head of a computation laboratory very seldom checks programs — for which purpose there are programmer-mathematicians (of which we have two, whom the authors stubbornly persist in calling girls). The description of materialization exercises in the first chapter of Part Two is done in a repugnant manner: examples of wild terminology that must remain on the conscience of the authors include, “vector magistatum” and “Auers’ incantation.” The Stokes equation has no bearing whatsoever on materialization and Saturn could in no way be in the constellation of Libra at that time. (This last lapse, particularly, is all the more unforgivable since I was given to understand that one of the authors is a professional astronomer.) The list of these kinds of inaccuracies and incongruities could be extended with no great exertion, but I refrain from doing so, since the authors categorically refused to change a single item. They also refused to expunge the terminology that they did not understand: one said that it was necessary for the ambience, and the other — that it adds color. I was, by the way, forced to agree that the preponderant majority of the readers could not distinguish the correct from the erroneous terminology, and also that no matter what terminology was employed, no reasonable reader would believe it anyway.}
  \end{rightcolumn}
\shuffle
\end{paracol}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```